# What is Plastic SCM written in?

Tags: .net, wpf, macos, mono, plasticscm

I see they have a windows version that looks like WPF and a mac screenshot shows Mono in the title bar.

Is it written in C# .NET with Mono?

(I'm only asking because they seem to do it right)

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you not choose the answer by a Codice employee?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably written in C# and it definitely runs on Mono on other platforms than Windows. You can see it in [FAQ requirements section](http://www.codicesoftware.com/opsupport2/opfaq2.aspx). Also their [PNUnit](http://www.codicesoftware.com/opdownloads2/oppnunit.aspx) is running on C#/Mono.

Answer (score 5):

A nice mix of different languages ranging from C# to Java. But, as Tomi pointed, C# is the primary language. Great to write code and very good in terms of performance too (able to consistently beat a good number of competitors).